# Validation engine with message over select field

Tags: validation, requiredfieldvalidator, jquery-validation-engine

I have a form here using the validation engine, I would like to have it so that if someone clicks on "no experience" a message comes up saying "you must have at least 1 year of experience" and they can't move on to submit the form if they have 1 year.

https://web.archive.org/web/20121129085036/http://www.barr-nunn.com/careers/form.php

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using on change function,

Ex :

```
$("#Selectbox").change(function(){
   var selecVal = $(this).val();
    if( selecVal == 'No Experience') {
         $('#Selectbox').attr("class","validate[required]");
     }
```

});

If you want pass custom message you do that also, refer this

> http://posabsolute.github.io/jQuery-Validation-Engine/

Answer (score 0):

By Using Jquery Validation Engine:

```
       <select  id="experience" class="validate[required]">
                <option >No Experience</option>
                <option >Below 1 yr</option>
                <option >1 yr</option>
                <option >Above 1 yr</option>
       </select>
```